# How to use website fonts inside print dialogue through website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created a website inside which I provide print functionality. I have used google Roboto font for website and it's working for it. But while printing the invoice through my website it doesn't support Roboto fonts. In my local system, I don't have Roboto fonts support.

I have tried the below mentioned things.

1. I have put below lines inside index.html inside `<head>`

   `link` tag and `@import` tag provided by google fonts [Link](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?preview.text_type=custom&sidebar.open=true&selection.family=Roboto)
2. I also tried `@font-face` (inside index.html `<style media="all" type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet"></style>`)

   ```
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Roboto";
        src: url("/fonts/Roboto.woff2") format("woff2"),
            url("/fonts/Roboto.woff") format("woff");
    }
   ```

How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: There is no difference between how you style your text for print vs. for on-screen.  Double check to make sure the paths to your fonts are correct.  You can preview your printable display with your browser's developer tools.

Comment: @Brad It's working for on-screen and also checked developer tools in which fonts are getting loaded properly. But for print dialogue it's not getting as needed.